# Will domain pointed at multiple IPs randomly redirect?

Tags: dns, load-balancing

Question: will a domain name with multiple A records pointed to different domains actually *pick one at random* for each user? I have seen people claim that, but is that really how it works?

Or would it behave more like -- everyone in New York goes to one IP, everyone somewhere else goes to another, etc?

I realize the more correct solution is to use a load balancer, but still want to know the answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its basics Round-Robin (what pointing a domain to multiple IPs or just having multiple records of the same type pointed to different destinations is) returns all IPs in "random" order and the client (the browser or other software the user uses) decides which IP to use. 
Commonly the first IP in the list is used. The next time there is a request for this record type the already used IP goes at the last place in the list and the second becomes first and so on.
This type of configuration by itself does not care where the request comes from or if this particular client already made a request and receive the same list.